# Правильный синтаксис команды

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

Подскажите ,пожалуйста ,как должна выглядеть команда `ls [-AabCcdFfghikLlmnopqRrstux1] [-timeout seconds] [-X attr] [pathname...]` для того чтобы она вывела мне атрибуты всех файлов с расширением txt из папки folder и всех ее подпапок .

Comment: Баш и винда? Это как?

Comment: Это через гитбаш

Comment: Только ls не обойтись. Нужен, например find

Comment: @AlexeyTen Не подскажите как в find работать с атрибутами файлов?

Comment: Вам нужно `man find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие конкретно атрибуты файлов Вам нужны?
`ls -lar | grep .txt` не подойдет?

Comment: Мне необходимы файлы для которых установлен атрибут архивный.

Comment: Не уверен, что с помощью bash можно отфильтровать по этому атрибуту. Так-как это чисто виндовая заморочка. Но могу ошибаться. Я, по крайней мере не сталкивался в линухе с таким атрибутом

Comment: вот такие задания дают в институте , спасибо за помощь уточню у преподавателя на этот счет .

Comment: `find` сделает это гораздо лучше.